# iptables: can't drop incoming DNS responses containing a specific IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, udp, pattern-matching, hexidecimal

I want to drop incoming DNS responses that contain `10.10.34.35`. How can I do that?

I tried to it this way:

`iptables -I INPUT -m udp -p udp --sport 53 -m string --algo kmp --hex-string '|31 30 02 31 30 02 33 34 02 33 35|' -j DROP`

But it simply doesn't drop them and I still receive them. However simply doing `iptables -I INPUT -m udp -p udp --sport 53 -j DROP` blocks all of them coming from port 53, but I want to select a portion of them which contain `10.10.34.35` as a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, DNS uses UDP **and** TCP.

Second, the wire representation of an A record is defined in RFC 1035 as such:

```
3.4.1. A RDATA format

    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |                    ADDRESS                    |
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

where:

ADDRESS         A 32 bit Internet address.
```

So an IPv4 address is not encoded as a string as you are attempting to match, but as a 32bits integer, so with the values 10, 10, 34, 35